# Python Sqlite, not able to print first line

Tags: python, sqlite, xlsx

Sqlite table structure:

```
id  sno
1   100
2   200
3   300
4   400

conn=sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("select * from abc")
mysel=c.execute("select * from abc where [id] = 1 ")
```

out put is:

```
1   100
```

its not printing **id** and **sno** i.e the First line of the table

how i can print First Line of table along with any kind of selection

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID` and `sno` are not data, they are part of your table structure (the column names).

If you want to get the names of the columns you need to do something like

```
connection = sqllite3.connect('test.sqlite')
cursor = connection.execute('select * from abc')
names = list(map(lambda x: x[0], cursor.description))
```

Comment: in my case they are part of DATA and first row of the table

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a 'first line' containing the column names, that's just something the command line client prints out by default to help you read the returned records.

A dbapi2 conforming cursor has an attribute [`description`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-attributes), which is a list of tuples containing information about the data returned by the last query. The first element of each tuple will be the name of the column, so to print the column names, you can do something similar to:

```
c.execute("select * from abc")
print(tuple(d[0] for d in c.description))
for row in c:
    print(row)
```

This will just print a tuple representation of the names and the records.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain details on the table you can use the following statement

```
PRAGMA table_info('[your table name]')
```

This will return a list of tuple with each tuple containing informations about a column

You will still have to add it to the data collected using the `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 0):

When you write `... WHERE id = 1`, you get only that particular record.

If you want to also get the first record, you have to tell SQLite that you want it:

```sql
SELECT id, sno FROM abc WHERE id = 'id'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, sno FROM abc WHERE id = 1
```

And when you already know what this particular subquery returns, you do not even need to bother with searching the table (and thus do not need to actually store the column names in the table):

```sql
SELECT 'id', 'sno'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, sno FROM abc WHERE id = 1
```